# Piped input to nano

Tags: ubuntu, centos, stdin, nano

Why does `ls | nano -` open the editor in Ubuntu but close the editor and save a file to `-.save` in CentOS?

How can I get nano in CentOS to remain open when reading stdin?

Comment: What are the nano versions in those distributions? Maybe the different behavior comes from an older version..

Comment: If your shell is `bash` try with process substitution: `nano <( ls )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature wasn't added until version 2.2

> http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/TODO
>
> For version 2.2:
>
> - Allow nano to work like a pager (read from stdin) [DONE]

and CentOS6 uses nano-2.0.9-7 (http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/)

If you decided you want the latest version, you can download from the upstream site (http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php) and then follow the Fedora guide to build your own RPM. (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package)

Comment: Or you can use the rpms provided by them. See https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/ then version then the rpm folder for red Hat/ fedora/ centos compatible rpms.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is text editor "feature" and nano doesn't have that.

you can use 2 steps:

```
ls > output.txt
nano output.txt
```

There are 2 other editors which can use stdin for data input

```
ls | joe
ls | jed
```